# How to Construct the Shared Access Signature URL using Python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, fine-uploader

Can someone please advise on how to return a SAS signature for fine-uploader so that I do not get the following error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

currently my fine-uploader instance is set up as following:

```
var uploader = new qq.azure.FineUploader({

        debug: true,
        element: document.getElementById("fine-uploader"),
        request: {
            endpoint: 'https://asilverman.blob.core.windows.net/picdepot'
        },
        cors: {
            //all requests are expected to be cross-domain requests
            expected: true,
            sendCredentials: true

        },
        signature: {
            customHeaders: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true},
            endpoint: '/sas'
        },
        uploadSuccess: {
            endpoint: ''
        },
        scaling: {
            sendOriginal: false,

            sizes: [
                {name: "", maxSize: 800}
            ]
        },
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png']
        }

    });
```

The server side that is handling the requests is doing the following:

```
@login_required
@app.route('/sas', methods=['GET'])
def sas():
    container_name = 'https://asilverman.blob.core.windows.net/picdepot'
    sas = SharedAccessSignature(account_name=app.config['AZURE_ACCOUNT'], account_key=app.config['AZURE_KEY'])
    access_policy = AccessPolicy()
    access_policy.start = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=-120)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
    access_policy.expiry = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=120)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
    access_policy.permission = 'w'
    sap = SharedAccessPolicy(access_policy)
    sas_token = sas.generate_signed_query_string(container_name, 'c', sap)
    return request.args['bloburi'] + '?' + sas_token + '&' + 'comp=list&restype=container'
```

Currently I am getting the following error (from chrome dev tools):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://asilverman.blob.core.windows.net/picdepot/8622a0a3-efb6-478b-891a-8…Mj1uvtPisX6s=&sr=c&se=2015-08-23T22%3A35%3A47Z&comp=list&restype=container. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your storage container isn't properly configured. You'll need to ensure it includes appropriate CORS headers in responses. This is covered in detail in [the fine uploader azure docs](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/endpoint_handlers/azure.html).

Comment: Could you please help me decipher how to configure the container so that it includes the appropriate CORS headers?